# storing array value in hash key throws error

Tags: redis

I want to store the array of arrays in redis as hash key. But it throws the following error
MSET is working. Why HSET is not working?

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hset key val1 [[x, y], [z, w]] 
(error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hset' command
127.0.0.1:6379> hmset key val1 [[x, y], [z, w]] val2 [[1,2], [3,4]]
OK
```

How to store the above values in specific key redis?

and also

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hmset key val1 [[1, 2], [3, 4]] val2 [[a, b], [c, d]] 
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> hmset key val1 [["1", "2"], ["3", "4"]] val2 [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]] 
Invalid argument(s)
```

Why invalid arguments error is thrown if we have string symbol in array?

I want to store the following multiple hash data in redis. How to do that?

```
hmset key val1 [["1", "2"], ["3", "4"]] val2 [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Every field (val) in a Hash can hold a single string value. To see the results of the (2nd) successful command, just use [`HEGETALL`](http://redis.io/commands/hgetall) on your key:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hmset key val1 [[x, y], [z, w]] val2 [[1,2], [3,4]]
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall key
1) "val1"
2) "[[x,"
3) "y],"
4) "[z,"
5) "w]]"
6) "val2"
7) "[[1,2],"
8) "[3,4]]"
```

As you can clearly see, since space is `HSET`'s delimiter, you had actually created four fields (`val1`, `y],`, `w]]` and `[[1,2],`) with their respective values.

Similarly, for the 3rd statement:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hmset key val1 [[1, 2], [3, 4]] val2 [[a, b], [c, d]] 
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall key
 1) "val1"
 2) "[[1,"
 3) "2],"
 4) "[3,"
 5) "4]]"
 6) "val2"
 7) "[[a,"
 8) "b],"
 9) "[c,"
10) "d]]"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

It appears as if you'd like to store an array in a single Hash's field. You can only store the string representation of the array that way (i.e. you won't be able to access specific elements in the array), like so:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hmset key val1 "[[1, 2], [3, 4]]" val2 "[[\"a\", \"b\"], [\"c\", \"d\"]]"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall key
1) "val1"
2) "[[1, 2], [3, 4]]"
3) "val2"
4) "[[\"a\", \"b\"], [\"c\", \"d\"]]"
```